# How to send the output of %time to a file in Jupyter/IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

The magic command `%time` produces the time it takes to execute a given code segment (statement) to the output cell in Jupyter Notebook. I would like this to be appended on to a specified file instead.

My objective is to find the runtime of an algorithm in different settings. I am able to automate the parameters of the algorithm, although not able to store the output of the `%time` (and `%timeit`) magic command in a file for further processing.

Is this possible?

Comment: `%timeit` (but not `%time`) has a `-o` option which makes it return an object, so you can do `res = %timeit -o foo()`. Then you can get the numbers from res and write them to a file however you wish. For more flexibility, use the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) in the standard library.

Comment: @ThomasK That's nice. I'd be happier if you could post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Reposting as an answer:

`%timeit` (but not `%time`) has a `-o` option which makes it return an object, so you can do:

```
res = %timeit -o foo()
```

Then you can get the numbers from res and write them to a file however you wish.

For more flexibility, use the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) in the standard library.